# Does this grammar define right-associativity by right recursion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

I'm reading [this article](https://bocoup.com/blog/designing-an-exponentiation-operator-for-javascript) about adding the `**` operator to the EcmaScript spec where the author states the following:

> Exponentiation must be evaluated before multiplication and more
>   importantly, the BNF grammar must be written such that **the operator’s
>   right-associativity is clearly defined** (unlike
>   MultiplicativeExpression, which is left-associative).

And he defines the new non-terminal `ExponentiationExpression` symbol in the grammar as:

```
ExponentiationExpression : 
  UnaryExpression[?Yield]
  UnaryExpression[?Yield] ** ExponentiationExpression[?Yield]

MultiplicativeExpression[Yield] :
  ExponentiationExpression[?Yield]
  MultiplicativeExpression[?Yield] MultiplicativeOperator ExponentiationExpression[?Yield]
```

[This article](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs536.s08/course.hold/html/NOTES/3.CFG.html) states that:

> To write a grammar that correctly expresses operator associativity:
>
> - For left associativity, use left recursion.
> - For right associativity,
>     use right recursion.

It seems that he follows that rule and defines the associativity by using **right recursion** for the `ExponentiationExpression` here:

```
ExponentiationExpression -> UnaryExpression[?Yield] ** ExponentiationExpression[?Yield]
```

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. (Some languages with exponentiation operators give exponentiation precedence over unary minus, so that `-2**4` has the value `-16`, which is possibly less surprising than `16`.) I didn't check your references to see if that is mentioned.)

Comment: @rici, thanks. `-16` is probably unexpected since this contradicts math, right? Also ES spec uses a bit different notation: `E::T\nO` instead of `E -> T | O`. Do you know the name for this notation?

Comment: IIRC the ES standard uses `:` for syntactic productions and `::` for lexical productions. That is entirely idiosyncratic.

Comment: @rici, yeah, they mention that, but I was asking about `E->T` vs `E::T` difference more. I guess it's idiosyncratic as you say

Comment: Yes, I meant that the choice of how to write "produces" is entirely idiosyncratic, and that ES introduces another idiosyncracy by writing it in two different ways. Now that I've glanced at the article you link, I see that the precedence question was raised repeatedly in the comments thread but the proposal's author seems to be unable to understand the point.

Comment: @rici, thanks. And [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-ExponentiationExpression) it shows that the current ES implementation gives unary operator higher precedence than exponentiation operator just as the author suggested

Comment: That's a standard, not an implementation, so it means that the (incorrect imho) precedence will be a permanent idiosyncracy in ES, making it different from PHP, D, Haskell, Python and Lua (and, iirc, Fortran). There's a long discussion thread [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/exponentiation-operator-precedence) which I didn't read to the end, but it appears that the argument that almost every other language does it differently did not make much difference to the proposal's supporters. Anyway, it makes little or no difference to me, since I don't exponentiate in ES very often...

Comment: ... and this is obviously not the place to have this discussion, anyway, particularly since it doesn't even relate to the OP.

Comment: @rici, thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I              right?

**Yes**.